# Cannot use applet in HTML

Tags: java, applet, embedded-resource, japplet

I have this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MainApp extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7076767216192554828L;
    JButton begin = new JButton(new ImageIcon("splash.png"));
    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    begin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            begin();
        }

    });
    add(begin);
    setVisible(true);
}
private void begin() {
    remove(begin);
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //to be used later
}
}
```

It works perfectly when seen in the applet viewer in Eclipse. However, in HTML, it fails:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
<body>
<APPLET code="MainApp.class" width="300" height="300"> Applet unavailable </APPLET> <br>
<a href="essay.docx"> Essay </a> (right click, Save Target As, in the menu under the name change it to "All Files," save as "essay.docx")
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, it gives a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`! I looked up the exception and found nothing helpful.

Before I used the `.png` for the button. everything was fine. I also added the `repaint()`, but that couldn't have made a difference.

Comment: Where is the `splash.png` located relative to the HTML, or the applet Jars?  That image must be accessed by `URL` rather than `String`, since the `String` is interpreted as a `File` path, and the applet cannot load a `File` from the server, only an `URL`.

Comment: So how do I get a URL for an image? The image is in the folder that contains the HTML file. Oh wait never mind, anselm's comment has it.

Comment: `setSize(300, 300);`  The size of an applet should be set in the HTML.  Don't attempt to resize it from within the code.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The image is in the folder that contains the HTML file.

```
// called from somewhere in the methods (e.g. init()) of the applet class 
URL urlToImage = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "splash.png");
begin = new JButton(new ImageIcon(urlToImage));
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The applet can't find the `splash.png` file, did you include it in the applet Jar?

Comment: The applet doesn't have a jar.

Comment: Try hardcoding `JButton begin = new JButton(new imageIcon("splash.png"));` to something like `JButton begin = new JButton(new imageIcon("http://localhost/splash.png"));` also check your applet console it may have outputted some error.

Comment: Nope, the console had no error. Actually, the applet showed, and then it said "Error. Click here for details." I'll post a website tomorrow. Actually I'll upload a .zip on mediafire instead. But in eclipse's applet viewer it worked perfectly!